# Adding commas between post titles on an archive page?

Tags: php, archives

I am working on my archive.php, which is used by several different custom post types.

On the archive pages, I would like post titles to display with commas between them (but not after the final post), e.g.:

Title 1, Title 2, Title 3

This is the code I currently have, but my if statement isn't working. I'm very new to PHP and WP, so any help is very much appreciated.

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            echo '<a href="', the_permalink(), '">', the_title(), '</a>';
            if ((current_post) < (post_count-1)) {
                echo ', ';
            }
        }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ultimately want the last post, regardless of pages, then you need to use `found_posts`.

This could change depending on how you sort but I didn't see any modifications to that in your code.

So to just modify the content of your code above you would do this:

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        $count = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->post_count;
        $total = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts;
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            echo '<a href="'. get_the_permalink(). '">'. get_the_title(). '</a>';
            if ($count != $total) {
                echo ', ';
            }
        }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Another way to do this could be to add the lines to an array and then implode it:

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        $myPosts = array();
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            $myPosts[] = '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a>';
        }
        echo implode(', ', $myPosts)
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Notice I changed `the_title` to `get_the_title` and `the_permalink()` to `get_the_permalink()` so we could echo instead of just displaying the them. I also changed your concatenators from a `,` to `.`.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! The first code example didn't work for me (perhaps because I do have a function to sort posts alphabetically), but the second one worked perfectly once I added a semicolon at the end of the echo line.